# Solve this, please

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, $\space BE \space$ is a median, and $O$ the mid-point of $BE$. The line joining $A$ and $O$ meets $BC$ at $D$. Find the ratio $\space AO : OD \space$ (Hint: Draw a line through $\space E \space$ parallel to $\space AD$.)

using BPT in first triangle BEP, we get relation b/w OD and EP. Similarly using BPT in second triangle we get relation between AD and EP. Thus, ultimately we get relation between AD and OD. Using this we can find the ratio of AO and OD. Am I right?

Comment: Were you able to obtain any extra information?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Niranjan Shinde I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  I am very much poor in mathematics. I am not even able to find a starting point to this problem. Please tell me the answer.

Comment: @Niranjan Shinde please share your ideas or any progress, Or else your question will get more downvotes.

Comment: @Keshav Sharma I have presented this question as it is. I have not altered any details in this question.

Comment: @NiranjanShinde that is what I am telling, please also write alongside with the problem your work, what you have done, and/or any ideas that you have related to problem,

Comment: @Keshav Sharma I tried the question for some more time and got the answer as 3:1 please tell me if it is right.

Comment: Hint: Draw line through E parallel to AD, let this line meet BC at P, consider the triangle BEP, O is mid point of BE and OD is parallel to EP. Is there any other such triangle?  Now try to continue

Comment: @Keshav Sharma, using BPT in first triangle BEP, we get relation b/w OD and EP. Similarly using BPT in second triangle we get relation between AD and EP. Thus, ultimately we get relation between AD and OD. Using this we can find the ratio of AO and OD. Am I right?

Comment: @Niranjan Shinde, yes

Comment: @Keshav Sharma Thanks a lot. I am new to MSE and I didn't know about its rules. Thanks for your Suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** $AE=EC \space, BO = OE, \space AD \mid\mid EF, \space OD \mid \mid EF$;

So, in triangle $\space ADC \space$ we have: $\space AD \mid \mid EF, \space$ hence by basic proportionality theorem we also have:

$$\frac{CE}{EA} = \frac{CF}{FD}.$$

Since $AE=EC, \space$ we will have:

$$1=\frac{CF}{FD} \iff CF=FD. \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (1)$$

Now, in triangle $\space BEF \space$ we have: $\space EF \mid \mid OD, \space$ hence by basic proportionality theorem we also have:

$$\frac{FD}{DB} = \frac{EO}{OB}.$$

Since $BO = OE, \space$ we will have:

$$\frac{FD}{DB}=1 \iff FD=DB. \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (2)$$

So, we know: $\space \boxed{CF=FD=DB \iff CF=FD=DB=\frac{1}{3}CB, \space CD=\frac{2}{3}CB.\space}$

Finally, in triangles $\space ADC \space$ and $\space BEF \space$ we also have:

$AD:CD=EF:FC
\\
OB:OD=EB:EF$

$$ \iff EF=\frac{AD}{CD}FC, \space \space \space \frac{OB}{OD}=\frac{EB}{\frac{AD}{CD}FC}=\frac{EB\cdot CD}{AD \cdot FC}.$$

Since we have $\space OB=\frac{t_B}{2}, \space OD=y, \space CD=\frac{2}{3}CB, \space AD=x+y, \space FC=\frac{1}{3}CB, \space$ we can write:

$$\frac{\frac{t_B}{2}}{y}=\frac{t_B\cdot \frac{2}{3}CB}{(x+y)\cdot \frac{1}{3}CB} \iff \frac{1}{2y}=\frac{2}{x+y} \iff 4y = x+y\iff 3y =x \iff \boxed{\space \frac{x}{y}=3. \space}$$

**Figure:**

[image]

Comment: This is quite convoluted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a mid-point of $DC$.

Thus, since $E$ is a mid-point of $AC$, we obtain $EF||AD$, $$BD=DF=FC,$$ $$EF=2OD$$ and $$AD=2EF.$$
Id est, $$\frac{AO}{OD}=\frac{AD-OD}{OD}=\frac{4OD-OD}{OD}=3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Say $EF =2z$, then we have

- $OD =z$ since $\Delta BOD\sim \Delta BEF$ and
- $AZ = 4z$ since $\Delta CAD\sim \Delta CEF$

So $AO=3z$ and thus $${AO\over OD} =3$$